# return false is not working in then and bind function with lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

I'm using `.then` function and `_.bind` function in a series. I want to stop the function execution,(i.e) the output of the previous function is input for next function.  Here is my code.

```
return getProducts(barcode, sku)
.then(_.bind(this.checkForPrice, this))
.then(_.bind(this.addLinkedProducts, this))
.then(null, _.bind(this.handleUnknownError, this));
```

In the `checkForPrice` function, I'm  using return false to stop the execution like below, but it didn't stop the flow.

```
checkForPrice: function (products) {
                debugger;
                if (!products) {
                    return false;
                }

                return something;
}
```

Kindly help to resolve this issue.

Comment: What do you mean by "stop the execution"? Did you try throwing an error?

Comment: @thefourtheye. I want to stop the next function. I didn't tried to throw error

Comment: Returning a value will simply fall down the chain and go to the next then handler. Please try to throw an error.

Comment: @thefourtheye . let me try that.

Comment: @thefourtheye. It's working. if i throw an error, it stops the chain. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As per @thefourtheye 's comment, if i throw an error, it stops the chain.